# Typescript - Merge two dynamically processed enum into one

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings

```
/* I have enum A & B at first */
enum A {
  FOO = 'BAR',
  GAR = 'ZAR'
}

enum B {
  FOO = 'BAR'
}


/* Is there any way to retrieve something merged like this? */
enum Merged {
  A_FOO = 'A_BAR',
  A_GAR = 'A_ZAR',
  B_FOO = 'B_BAR'
}
```

I have 2 `enum`s and I cannot guarantee their keys are mutually exclusive. Also, I want to pre-process their values before merging as well.

May I know if there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a type for this is possible, but not until TS 4.1, which gives us [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707).

In TS 4.1 you can define a helper type `Prefix`, which does the magic:

```
type Prefix<T extends { [K in keyof T]: string }, P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as `${P}_${K}`]: `${P}_${T[K]}`
}
```

Then, it is straightforward to define a `Merge` function which uses this type to construct a merged enum.

```
function merged<
  T1 extends { [K in keyof T1]: string }, P1 extends string,
  T2 extends { [K in keyof T2]: string }, P2 extends string,
>(obj1: T1, prefix1: P1, obj2: T2, prefix2: P2): Prefix<T1, P1> & Prefix<T2, P2> {
  const result = {} as any; // Going to have to cast somewhere anyways...

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
    result[`${prefix1}_${k}`] = `${prefix1}_${v}`;
  }

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    result[`${prefix2}_${k}`] = `${prefix2}_${v}`;
  }

  return result;
}

const Merged = merged(A, 'A', B, 'B')
console.log(Merged) // { A_FOO: "A_BAR", A_GAR: "A_ZAR", B_FOO: "B_BAR" }
```

You can try this out on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUBiB5dUC8UDkAQjAEp4A0yUA4iTvgFol6IC+iiokUBClGWuQk1bsALgE8ADsCgAFAE7AAZgEsAHgB4AKlGBrRoACYBnBFADaAaSgqQUANbBxAeyVQtAXQBcUY6Pm2AOZQLGRyuvpGpn4BIIEAfHRIKFY2do4ubjoAZL7+QVAAhqYABgAk8LIsAPoVliwl3lDllTUVWlYeDSKISmAgAMaiKs52EMDygcCGGpRaAIwRBiAmZqm2Dk6u7vNNMQWhcot6y6v7cRQoWgBMS1Fr1hsZ2zd7+XEhYbK3J-fngRR4gAKZwAIwAVvMfAswpJFKo1FCjmEweDrtDrrD4ep0XJrgBKHwKZTqbTzL7zRK5YkI7SYvGJZJQAajPxQRTGMAAG1ESRYRVMhRA4gA3OwUEpnPIoECWSA2eZ7GEAG4eKDbdAQ4BDAB0oHywGMIIh83x+N4KBQHO5onMLThJMRbXg9gaatw9uxTtq8GVDTFKDYlEl0tlrN5ipVao1Wt1+oChuNaLNFst1p5doqDoR12drsadE9jtzPr9JQDIXF7OAojA8js6dEYqDcrZAFkJlNDHRxpNpkCYGE8DByNwhwQ8PjEK3nFzgDquc5AkCO33DPigA), or install `typescript@next` in your project. TS 4.1 is planned to release on November 17th.

Comment: Thanks. It takes me a day to understand. However, I have try to modify it to be used without merge function, but not luck? May I know that can I achieve it without using helper function?

Comment: Do you mean just having the type and that magically giving you another value? You can't do that... types are compile time only.